# What is a propper way to implement MKAnnotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm getting crashes while working with `MKAnnotation` implementation

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSRangeException`, reason: `Cannot remove an observer MKMapAnnotationManager for the key path "coordinate" from DevicesGroupAnnotation because it is not registered as an observer.`

I've implemented coordinate property in following way

```
@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;
@synthesize deviceInfos = _deviceInfos;

- (void)setDeviceInfos:(NSArray *)deviceInfos {
    _deviceInfos = deviceInfos;
    self.coordinate = [[self class] coordinateFromDeviceInfosGroup:self.deviceInfos];
}

- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate {
    _coordinate = newCoordinate;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What requirements exists on coordinate property implementation?

Comment: It seems problem with your Notification settings. Are you adding and removing those annotations frequently?

Comment: @Mrunal I'm sorry, what is "Notification settings"? Yep, I'm adding and removing annotations frequently.

Comment: @BergP are you implementing custom annotation?

Comment: This seems a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012067/mkmapview-removing-annotation-causes-app-crash

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman Yes I am.

Comment: Then you are missing two required methods of MKAnnotation that is `-(NSString *)title` and `-(NSString *)subtitle`

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman no, they are optional

Comment: is this your class method `coordinateFromDeviceInfosGroup`?

Comment: may be coordinate are not valid, thats causing to remove the coordinate observer. check once if coordinates are valid with CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid().

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman Yep, it is class method

Comment: I cant understand that why you are not calling the class method like this `self.coordinate = [self coordinateFromDeviceInfosGroup:self.deviceInfos];`

Comment: also when this statement is called `self.coordinate = [self coordinateFromDeviceInfosGroup:self.deviceInfos];` your second setter function will be called which is `- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate`

Comment: I have always seen this "cannot remove observer" error with annotations when the coordinates are not valid.  Make sure the latitude is from -90 to +90 and the longitude is from -180 to +180.